# std::unique_ptr with RAII for mutex?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, unique-ptr

We have a lot of legacy C++98 code that we are slowly upgrading to c++11 and we have a RAII implementation for custom Mutex class:

```
class RaiiMutex
{
public:
    RaiiMutex() = delete;
    RaiiMutex(const RaiiMutex&) = delete;
    RaiiMutex& operator= (const RaiiMutex&) = delete;
    RaiiMutex(Mutex& mutex) : mMutex(mutex)
    {
        mMutex.Lock();
    }
    ~RaiiMutex()
    {
        mMutex.Unlock();
    }
private:
    Mutex&  mMutex;
};
```

Is it ok to make an std::unique_ptr of this object? We would still benefit from automatically calling the destructor when the object dies (thus unlocking) and would also gain the ability of unlocking before non-critical operations.

Example legacy code:

```
RaiiMutex raiiMutex(mutex);
if (!condition)
{
    loggingfunction();
    return false;
}
```

After:

```
auto raiiMutex = std::unique_ptr<RaiiMutex>(new RaiiMutex(mutex));
if (!condition)
{
    raiiMutex = nullptr;
    loggingfunction(); // log without locking the mutex
    return false;
}
```

It would also remove the use of unnecessary brackets:

Example legacy code:

```
Data data;
{
    RaiiMutex raiiMutex(mutex);
    data = mQueue.front();
    mQueue.pop_front();
}
data.foo();
```

After:

```
auto raiiMutex = std::unique_ptr<RaiiMutex>(new RaiiMutex(mutex));
Data data = mQueue.front();
mQueue.pop_front();
raiiMutex = nullptr;
data.foo();
```

Does it make sense?

Edit:
Cannot use unique_lock due to custom Mutex class:

```
class Mutex
{

public:
    Mutex();
    virtual ~Mutex();

    void Unlock(bool yield = false);
    void Lock();
    bool TryLock();
    bool TimedLock(uint64 pWaitIntervalUs);

private:
    sem_t mMutex;
};
```

Comment: If you're using C++11 why not just use a `std::unique_lock`?

Comment: You can use std::lock_guard (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), with std::mutex.

Comment: In your implementation only one thread can lock the mutex, so why using a mutex at all?

Comment: @gerum The `Mutex&` argument to the ctor is probably what is shared between different threads!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, you are right, I do not see the &.

Comment: using additional brackets would remove the need for a `std::unique_ptr`. Imho its not a good idea to use dynamic allocation merely to save some brackets

Comment: you are actually moving away from RAII, rather than following the typical pattern of simply letting things go out of scope

Comment: @WBuck unfortunately I can not use unique_lock wrapper because of custom Mutex class provided in sdk without lock() and unlock() methods:
class Mutex
{

public:
 Mutex();
 virtual ~Mutex();

 void Unlock(bool yield = false);
 void Lock();
 bool TryLock();
 bool TimedLock(uint64 pWaitIntervalUs);

private:
 sem_t mMutex;
};

Comment: OK, so in this case, don't use the `std::unique_ptr`, the last thing you want to do is an unnecessary dynamic allocation. Stick with your `RAII` wrapper. I would provide a `ctor` which allows a user to pass in an already locked `mutex` though.

Comment: @Daniko you can with a wrapper: `class MutexWrapper { Mutex & wrapped; public: MutexWrapper(Mutex & wrapped) : wrapped(wrapped) {} void lock() { wrapped.Lock(); } bool try_lock() { return wrapped.TryLock(); } void unlock() { wrapped.Unlock(); } };`.

Comment: And if you are updating legacy code why are you updating to something I would call legacy as well?

Comment: @Caleth that would be adding an extra wrapper just to use lock_guard. I do not see the potential benefit over the already implemented RaiiMutex

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Embedded devices be like that, ARM compiler 5 only supports c++11

Comment: gcc and clang both support ARM and ARM64 and c++20 and even c++23 partially.

Comment: @Daniko not just `std::lock_guard`, anything written for the *Lockable* concept

Answer (score 2):

Add `Mutex::lock()`, `Mutex::unlock()` and `Mutex::try_lock()` methods to `Mutex`.  They just forward to the `Lock` etc methods.

Then use `std::unique_lock<Mutex>`.

If you cannot modify `Mutex`, wrap it.

```
struct SaneMutex: Mutex {
  void lock() { Lock(); }
  // etc

  using Mutex::Mutex;
};
```

A `SaneMutex` replaces a `Mutex` everywhere you can.

Where you can't:

```
struct MutexRef {
  void lock() { m.Lock(); }
  // etc
  MutexRef( Mutex& m_in ):m(m_in) {}
private:
  Mutex& m;
};
```

include an adapter.

these match the C++ standard lockable requirements.  If you want timed lockable, you have to write a bit of glue code.

```
auto l = std::unique_lock<MutexRef>( mref );
```

or

```
auto l = std::unique_lock<SaneMutex>( m );
```

you now have `std::lock`, `std::unique_lock`, `std::scoped_lock` support.

And your code is one step closer to using `std::mutex`.

As for your unique_ptr solution, I wouldn't add the overhead of a memory allocation on every time you lock a mutex casually.